# Cannot update Debian container in Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Running Docker for Windows 18.09.2 with Docker Desktop 2.0.0.3 *31259, trying to update an Debian container via apt-get update.

```
First I pull the latest images:
    > docker pull debian
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/debian
5ae19949497e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:903779f30a7ee46937bfb21406f125d5fdace4178074e1cc71c49039ebf7f48f
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:latest
> docker run -d -ti --name d1 debian
d1fce4047033d6321740f98315b2ec050ca946c835625927065d413f21fd216d
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d1fce4047033        debian              "bash"              2 seconds ago       Up 1 second                             d1
```

Then I connect to the container and try to make an update:

```
$ winpty docker exec -ti d1 bash
root@d1fce4047033:/# uname -a
Linux d1fce4047033 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@d1fce4047033:/# apt-get clean
root@d1fce4047033:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@d1fce4047033:/# ping 212.211.132.250
PING 212.211.132.250 (212.211.132.250) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 212.211.132.250: icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=18.5 ms
^C
--- 212.211.132.250 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 6ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.406/19.176/20.597/1.012 ms
    root@d1fce4047033:/# wget
bash: wget: command not found
root@d1fce4047033:/# curl
bash: curl: command not found
```

As you can see, the update fails but I have internet connection. Tried several times, but have no luck.
Because it's the same behavior as when I try to pull Ubuntu or something else, I assume not a simple reason behind.
I have tested the download of one of these files on a busybox via wget and it works. Also when I try to download the site via browser. So what's happens here?

Comment: Same error today

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be a firewall rule blocking requests from inside your container. Sometimes the firewall is configured to accept ICMP requests (ping) but block TCP/UPD traffic. Maybe you could check what the result of `iptables -L` is on your host.

Comment: It's windows Defender Firewall. Can I check on windows whether that's the reason could be?

Comment: You could try deactivating the Firewall for a short amount of time in order to test the update again and reactivate it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly fix is to change mirror with source by `sed`